# How to check if a Polynomial has a specific form

Tags: polynomials

I have a polynomial `F[x]`, for example `F[x] = 1 - 2x + x^2`. I wanna check whether F[x] has the form of `(1 + kx)^n`. For the example above, `k = -1` and `n = 2`.

I have searched on several documents but found nowhere has the answer. So can I do this on Mathematica? If yes, how can I get k and n?

Comment: $n$ is going to be the order of the polynomial f[x]. Then $k^n$ is the coefficient of $x^n$, so $k=coef^{(1/n)}$. Then test to see if `f[x]` is the same as `(1+k x)^n`.

Comment: @Kuba Oh I thought they are the same, aren't they? I mean it can be represented in that form.

Comment: Just done @Kuba :)

Comment: @bills what I wanna do is that I send the polynomial to Mathematica, simplify it and then check the question above automatically. If Mathematica is not capable of doing that then I will have to put more manual work like your suggestion. Thank you anw.

Comment: Have you tried `Factor` or `Simplify` on F[x]?

Answer (score 3):

It may be naive but I think the following should work:

If the polynomial has this form this means it has one multiple root which is not `0`:

```
check[f_?PolynomialQ] := Length@DeleteDuplicates@Solve[f[x] == 0, x] == 1 && f[0] != 0

check[f]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Notice that I'm not bothering about `n` and `k`. Do you want to find them?

---

It works even for not so exact coefficients:

```
f[x_] := (1/5 - 1/3 x)^5 // Expand // N
f[x]
```

> ```
> 0.00032 - 0.00266667 x + 0.00888889 x^2 - 0.0148148 x^3 + 0.0123457 x^4 - 0.00411523 x^5
> ```

```
check[f]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
f[x_] := (1/5 + 1/3 x)^5 + 2 // Expand // N
check[f]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: It's a good idea. Since Mathematica will return all the roots hence we can check whether they are duplicated roots. Then we can find N consequently. I think K is then easily found since 1/k is the only root of the `F[X] == 0` right?

Comment: @Loi.Luu I just have to add that root equal to `0` should be excluded as it does not fit your form.

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: @Loi.Luu ok it should work now :)